# Delete linkbutton not firing inside a gridview inside an update panel

Tags: .net, gridview, updatepanel

Looked to various posts on here but couldn't find one quite like it, I know this is going to be something small but I just can't figure it out.

I am using a gridview inside an update panel. The gridview is using the auto generated delete column converted into a templatefield column. Here is the code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvFiles" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
        CellPadding="4"
        ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
        <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Files" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">

            <ItemStyle Width="210px" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#Eval("Id", "~/Download.aspx?id={0}")%>'><%#Eval("LinkName")%></asp:HyperLink>,<br />
                Last Modified: <%#Me.cutDate(Eval("DateModified"))%>
            </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" HeaderText="Team">
            <ItemStyle Width="150px" />
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%#Me.GetTeamName(Eval("TeamId"))%>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbDelete" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this post?');"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    </asp:GridView>
```

I've got this exact same code working fine when it's not inside the update panel. What do I need to do to get this to work?

Edit: Forgot to mention, my update panel settings are all default. Also what happens is you click delete, the confirmation message pops up, you click Yes, and then nothing happens.

Comment: do you catch this event in onCommand's event handeler???

Comment: No, should I be? Why does it need that specific event handle only when inside an update panel?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with the edit button only, all the others worked fine which I thought was odd.  So I added an onclick event to the edit button that rebound the gridview and it worked.  With breakpoints I saw that the gridview set the editIndex correctly on the first click but didn't change to the editItem templates until the second click.  Hope this gives you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to add this

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnFindOrder" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: I assume the ControlID should be "lbDelete", and I tried that, but it says `A control with ID 'lbDelete' could not be found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.`

Comment: lbDelete is inside the gridview which means it will have an id of ctrl001_gvFiles_(something)_lbDelete.  It's something like that.  Run the page and then look for lbDelete.  The issue with this though is that each row created will have a different ID for lbDelete and it should increment it.